# How do I change script language from C# to UnityScript?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

When I click my script in Unity (Which has the C# symbol), it opens MonoDevelop with C# code, but I want to write code using UnityScript instead, how do I go about doing this?

Comment: I recommend using C# instead. It's more flexible than its JS equivalent.

Comment: @ManoDestra you're right, and I feel much more confident with C#, but I'm only a games development student making a quick low poly survival game, but thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: And C# is still far better for Unity development regardless of experience level, but it's up to yourself :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right Click inside the Project Tab, go to Create->Javascript.

[image]

Comment: This picture is worth more then 1000 words. Good job. Some beginners can use it.

Comment: And yes, agreed. Thank you for your help @Programmer!

Comment: @JerrySwitalski You are both welcome. Tim, Remember the advice from ManoDestra. Go with C#. You will get more help with it on SO too.